# Is "hayway" an English word?

Tags: meaning, etymology, is-it-a-word

I thought I had heard and seen this word being used. For example,

> If you do this, things will go hayway.

Meaning that things will go out of order in a mess/berserk, something like that.
Now I cannot find any such word in existence.

Comment: I think you mean *haywire*

Comment: The word you want is [haywire](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/haywire).

Comment: Thanks guys. That's the one. This was eating my head. Feel relaxed now. :)

Comment: What's... with all.....the periods....sure looks.......like...a key.... is jammed...

Answer (score 4):

The word you're after is *haywire*. According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/haywire):

> **Adjective**
>
> ...
>
> 2. Behaving erratically or uncontrollably, especially of a machine or mechanical process; usually used with the verb "go".
>
> - *It was working fine until it went **haywire** and wouldn't stop printing blank sheets.*
> - *Those kids go **haywire** when they don't get what they want.*

Comment: ... and what does *hay* have to do with *haywire*?  Or, for that matter, what does *wire* have to do with it?

Comment: The OED says hay wire was wire for binding hay. It also referred to something poorly made, from using hay wire for makeshift repairs. A haywire person is confused and tangled and crazy. To go haywire is to go wrong, become excited or distracted, or mentally unbalanced.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the word which is most likely to be used in this context is *haywire* which is often used to mean that some sort of equipment started malfunctioning in the way you described, but I want to add that hayway also rhymes with *mayday* which is used to initiate distress calls. Both of these words are often used in contexts of a disaster (especially crashes), and sometimes even come in close proximity to each-other as a result. This is exemplified in this passage story [Checkmate! found in Fabulous Short Stories by Stan Morrison (©2014)](https://books.google.com/books?id=vgi_BAAAQBAJ&lpg=PT156&dq=mayday%2C%20%22everything%20went%20haywire%22&pg=PT146#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> ‘This is C-Zero-Two-G calling base,’ I yelled into the microphone. ‘I’m losing altitude. May-Day! May-Day! [Redacted] Bells! I’m about to have to make a forced landing and the terrain doesn’t look too good down there. It should be forrest down there but it’s made up of mountains. We entered a black cloud and then everything went haywire. All the instruments have gone crazy so I can’t give you our location.'

Or this passage from *Thriller in a Stricken Plane scotch and Diapers went, but Dolls and Bibles stayed* found on [page 38 of the March 29th 1963 issue of Life Magazine](https://books.google.com/books?id=pkwEAAAAMBAJ&lpg=PA38-IA2&pg=PA38-IA2#v=onepage&f=false):

> On the sweep of his 180° turn Ekelund’s No. 3 engine—on the same wing as the dead No. 4—went out of synchronization, went completely haywire. Ekelund feathered No. 3, urgently radioed his distress call—”Mayday…Mayday…Mayday.”

It is therefore not beyond cognition that somebody may have jumbled them together, either intentionally to somehow  combine their signification with a nonce word, or perhaps more likely as a mistake made while in a panic, in which case it lacks the actual meaning necessary to be considered anything more than a mere utterance of gibberish as of yet.

Either way, I never actually heard or read any usage of hayway before, and the massive two volume Shorter Oxford English Dictionary 5th edition (©2002), which is actually even longer than even most other unabridged dictionaries, lacks an entry for Hayway. The closest entry is Haywire, found on page 1208 of volume 1 A–M.

I therefore doubt that it is an established word, especially since you can not find it yourself despite your advantage in possibly having heard it straight from the horse's mouth.